# dynamic img control from string

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, source-control-bindings

I have to create dynamic img inside div & my src contains binary string but it is showing me blank when I do this. Please help/guid me

```
var body="data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
var contentTexarea = '<img src="' + body + '" style="height:150px; min-width:100%" />';
objList.parents('.mystream-wrapper').after("<div class='mystream-wrapper'>" +
                        "<input type='hidden' class='quibId' value='" + Id + "'>" +
                        SeedSymbol +
                        "<input class='myStreamQuibTime mystream-time' readonly='true' value='QUIB ZERO'/>" +
                        contentTexarea +
                        "<div style='clear: both; margin: 4px 0; height: 16px'>" +
                        contentPostDelete +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>");
```

but when I am binding this text into div then it is not appearing.

Comment: `quibContent.Body` on the second line should just be `body`

Comment: I have edited the question...I have var body for just reference only...but it showing me blank image box (white box)...